# Auto login to travian kingdoms - selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to login automatically to browser game (https://kingdoms.com/com) to make some upgrades automatically. But I am struggling with login screen. Steps are really simple (you can see from the picture)

1- click login button.

2- new windows is opening and I think it is a new frame.

3- finding frame class in order to switch main frame to new frame.

I also tried to fill the email box directly without switching frames. It did not work.

[click here to see picture - login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvEND.png)

**My code is here:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://kingdoms.com/com")

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
loginButton = driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
frame_login = driver.find_element_by_class_name("mellon-iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_login)

driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("@gmail.com")
```

**See my error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\onder.lapcin\PycharmProjects\ProjectTest\Selenium_projects\travian_giris.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("@gmail.com")
  File "C:\Users\onder.lapcin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\onder.lapcin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\onder.lapcin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\onder.lapcin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="email"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

Comment: Your screenshot fails to show any element named `email`.  Though that login screen is in an iframe, so you need to look at the contents of the iframe

Comment: I know and I also checked the element of the mail adress box, it seems as a "email".

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the my mistake. There are two frames.
I am switching to main frame to second frame. But I could not see the third frame to reach email and password box.

```
frame_login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='mellon-iframe']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_login)
frame_login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_login)
```

Now it works.